# Unit testing a Service method subscribed to an Observable in Angular

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, observable

I want to test this component using Jasmine:

```
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {
  movimiento: Movimiento;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private datosService: DatosService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(params => {
        const _id = params['id'].toString(); // recepción del parámetro
        this.datosService
          .getMovimientoBy_Id$(_id)
          .subscribe(r => this.movimiento = r); // consulta al servicio
      });
  }

}
```

This methods subscribes to an `Observable<Movement>` returned by the service. This is the `DatosService` `getMovimientoBy_Id$(_id)` method:

```
getMovimientoBy_Id$(_id): Observable<Movimiento> {
  return this.http
    .get(`priv/movimientos/${_id}`)
    .map(r => r.json());
}
```

I've tried this code to test the component:

```
describe('EditorComponent', () => {
  let movimiento = new Movimiento(new Date(), 0, 1, 1);
  let component: EditorComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditorComponent>;
  let datosService: DatosService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    let activatedRouteMock = {
      route: Observable.of({ id: 1 })
    }

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        EditorComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        DatosService,
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteMock }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditorComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    datosService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(DatosService);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should create movimiento', (done) => {
    let spy = spyOn(datosService, 'getMovimientoBy_Id$').and.returnValue(Observable.of(movimiento));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.movimiento).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

The first test passes, but in the second I'm getting this exception

> Uncaught Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong... Any ideas on what's going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular cli stopped adding second before each.

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditorComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    datosService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(DatosService);
  });
```

This make sense since you usually want to mock data before you start testing.

But you actual problem is how you mock router. You need to add to **route** property **params** otherwise **params** is null

Try following:

```
describe('EditorComponent', () => {
  let movimiento = new Movimiento(new Date(), 0, 1, 1);


beforeEach(async(() => {
    let activatedRouteMock = {
      route: {
        params: {
          Observable.of({ id: 1 })
        }
      }
    }

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        EditorComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        DatosService,
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteMock }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    var component = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should create movimiento', (done) => {
    var datosService = TestBed.get(DatosService);
    let spy = spyOn(datosService, 'getMovimientoBy_Id$').and.returnValue(Observable.of(movimiento));

    var fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditorComponent);
    var component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.movimiento).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi! I created the project with the latest version `angular-cli` and it creates the two methods (the async and the sync one). Anyway, with your code I'm getting the same exception.

Comment: Finally I solved it, the problem is that `ActivatedRoute` doesn't have the route property, so declaring it like this: `let activatedRouteMock = {
      params: Observable.of({ id: 1 })
    }` works perfectly, that's why I was getting `undefined`.

Comment: @EliasGarcia but this is same as in your question

Comment: Yes i see params should be in the root ;0

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that, it's a merge of your answer and my error ;D